# PHP - CheckBoxes and Shopping Cart

Tags: php, checkbox, shopping-cart

I'm building a web page which communicate with a database of products. I'm searching in database for products and as a result I get for example 5 products with a checkbox next to each product. What I want to do is to select 3 products and add them with a button in a visible cart next to the results. So I need to save the selected products in a list in the same page in order to give user the possibility to search and add easily. With which way can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an checkbox with the same name like `product[]`, ... Each checkbox have the `value` attribute set to the id of the corresponding product. When you submit the form, you will receive `$_POST['product']` as an array of selected product id.

For example:

```
<div class="product">
  <p class="product-name">Product 1</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p class="product-name">Product 2</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p class="product-name">Product 3</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

`<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="your_product_id">`

`.. and all your other checkboxes`

PHP

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $product) //loop through the checkboxes
{
    // add to cart 
}
```

this should do what you are looking for